# Playback for AMR file format

Tags: android, android-ndk, amr

When I try to play the track with AMR file format. It throws a warning

Permission failure: android.permission.ALLOW_ANY_CODEC_FOR_PLAYBACK

and error from libOpenSLES

AudioSfDecoder::onPrepare: Could not find a supported audio track.

I tried setting the permission in manifest file.

```
    <!-- Allows an application to use any media decoder when decoding for playback
         @hide -->
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ALLOW_ANY_CODEC_FOR_PLAYBACK"
         android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"
         android:label="@string/permlab_anyCodecForPlayback"
         android:description="@string/permdesc_anyCodecForPlayback" />
```

But still throws the same error.

Am I setting the permission correctly?
Could anyone help me out, what am I missing.

Comment: show me your code,then i can help u

Comment: r u testing the app in device or emulator? and what about the version?

Comment: check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

AMR is not supported with the NDK on many devices.
You could use an external AMR library.
Use the PCM recorder/player and encode and decode manually with [opencore-amr](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/).

This works fine for me.

Towards your permission issue:

```
android.permission.ALLOW_ANY_CODEC_FOR_PLAYBACK
```

is no official permission, so why do you use this here?
There are no codec related permissions on Android I know of.

Important is only [Record_Audio](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECORD_AUDIO) for Microphone access.